# can `focus` only be on links?

Tags: html, focus

I wonder if the focus can only be on links and form elements or also on other elements. Especially on a one-pager site it would be necessary to jump to sections further down below, but not necessarily to a link, but for example a section header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links (`<a href>`). In recent browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property. An element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks on the element.

Edit: Or give the element a tabindex.